# Uploaded image attributes

Tags: media

I'm new to drupal and I'm using drupal 6 I want when I upload an image using imagefield  to display its width and height in pixels the only thing that appears after uploading is the image thumbnail, so any ideas?

Comment: Create a image style and put it into the cck image field settings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I think my question wasn't clear enough I don't want to change the size of the uploaded images but in the backend when the admin uploads  an image it gives him a thumbnail of the uploaded image instantly I want the size of that uploaded image to be displayed as well and again it's drupal 6